# Naturality of the Cup Product

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Let $f:X\to Y$ be a continuous map between topological spaces.
Let $A, B\subseteq X$ and $C, D\subseteq Y$ be such that $f(A)\subseteq C$ and $f(B)\subseteq D$.

> **Question.** Does the following diagram commute?
>   \begin{array}[rcl]
> HH^k(X, A)\times H^l(X, B) & \stackrel{\cup}{\longrightarrow} &  H^{k+l}(X, A+B)\\
> \qquad\qquad\  \uparrow & & \qquad\quad \uparrow\\
> H^k(Y, C)\times H^l(Y, D) & \stackrel{\cup}{\longrightarrow} & H^{k+l}(Y, C+D)
> \end{array}
>   where the vertical arrows are $(f^*)^k\times (f^*)^l$ and $(f^*)^{k+l}$ respectively.
>   Here $H^{k+l}(X, A+B)$ denotes the set of all the $k+l$-cochains in $X$ which vanish on all chains which are sums of $k+l$-chains in $A$ and $k+l$-chains in $B$. Sinimlarly for $H^{k+l}(Y, C+D)$.

I thikn the answer to the question is YES. For let us take $\phi\in Z^k(Y, C)$ and $\psi\in Z^l(Y, D)$.
Then the element $([\phi], [\psi])$ maps via the left vertical map to $([f^*\phi], [f^*\psi])$. This in turn maps to $[f^*\phi]\cup[f^*\psi]=[f^*(\phi\cup\psi)]$ under the top right horizontal map. On the other hand, $([\phi], [\psi])$ goes to $[\phi\cup\psi]$ under the lower horizontal map, and this in turn goes to $[f^*(\phi\cup \psi)]$ under the right vertical map.

Is this okay?

Comment: Yes, basically everything resides in the equality $[f^*\phi] \smile [f^*\psi] = [f^*(\phi \smile \psi)]$. The difficulty with relative cohomology is in verifying everything factors through the quotients, but the equalities don't really change. Is there a reason you were unsure about your proof?

Comment: Thanks. The thing is that I have just started reading cohomology and the concepts feel quite foreign as of now. Further, I couldn't find the exact same statement for naturality in Hatcher so I thought may be there is something wrong.

Comment: Well, if I can give some advice, basically there are two sorts of statements you can make about (co)homology: either statements that come from "high-level" properties (like computing the homology of spheres: you use Mayer--Vietoris, homotopy invariance...) or statements that you verify directly through computation on eg. singular (co)chains. Here it's the latter, and usually if you take the time to write down the corresponding equation it "just works".